# Paste Excel image to Word heading not working in Office 2013

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an Excel workbook which generates a Word document.  At one point it copies an Excel image into the heading of the generated Word document.  This code has worked in Office 2003, 2007, and 2010, but now in 2013 it fails on the Paste statement with a generic automation error in the Paste method.  I'm hoping someone can help me make this work in Office 2013.  To duplicate, define a macro workbook with a worksheet called "Logo" containing a single shape, add the following code, and execute the **doctop** subroutine:

```
Const wdCollapseEnd = 0
Const wdHeaderFooterPrimary = 1
Const wdPrintView = 3
Const wdSeekCurrentPageHeader = 9
Const wdSeekMainDocument = 0

Sub doctop()
    Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Document")
    wd.Application.Visible = True

    ' insert heading with logo
    Worksheets("Logo").Shapes(1).CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
    With wd.ActiveWindow.View
        .Type = wdPrintView
        .SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
    End With
    With wd.sections(1).headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Paste
    End With
    wd.ActiveWindow.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't have 2013 to test this on but you might try `wd.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteAsPicture"` (or "PasteBitmap", "PasteGif", "PastePng", "PasteJpeg").

Comment: Thanks David -- that worked perfectly.  Too bad I've got to make this change in several workbooks.

Comment: OK I'll add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I don't have 2013 to test, even on 2010 I have run in to some issues with certain commands which aren't exposed through the `Paste` or `PasteSpecial` options; specifically those relating to pasting between applications and preserving formatting/etc.

With that in mind, I'm guessing the `Mso` procedure should work.  Try:

```
wd.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PasteAsPicture"
```

Several others also you could test:

```
"PasteBitmap" 
"PasteGif"
"PastePng"
"PasteJpeg"
```